# How to get fm radio back after Desire X was updated to Android 4.1?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, htc-desire, fm-radio

My HTC Desire X recently updated to android 4.1. With that update, the FM radio disappeared. How can I get it back? I can't find an app the does this in the Play Store. Are there other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by restarting the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this forum: http://www.htcforums.com/desire-x/12477-updated-4-1-1-no-fm-radio.html. The only other way (I know) to get a fm radio on your device is to root it or install an .apk from outside the Play Store.

Answer (score -1):

Use Spirit Light. Works well on Desire, excellent app.

Comment: What spirit is light? I mean, with enough spiritus you hear everything, be it there or not... Maybe you could add a link and a little explanation what "Spirit Light" is? ;)

Comment: @Izzy lol! Maybe it's liquer spirits? JD on the rocks please! :D /ot

Comment: @t0mm13b Excellent! That gives the "on the Rocks" another dimension (it simply rocks on, and thanks to the spirit in the JD part, sounds even better than a full HiFi rack :D)